# How load cv2.KeyPoint and Descriptors correctly on OpenCV 3 with Python 3?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

The other day I had to resume an old project that I used with OpenCV 3 and Python 2.7.

On this code, to load cv2.KeyPoint i do:

```
    import numpy as np
    import cPickle
    import cv2
    keypoints_list = cPickle.loads(open(path).read())
    kp = []
    for point in keypoints_list:
        temp = cv2.KeyPoint(x=point[0][0], y=point[0][1], _size=point[1], _angle=point[2], _response=point[3],
                            _octave=point[4], _class_id=point[5])
        kp.append(temp)
```

For load descriptors i do:

```
    descriptors_list = cPickle.loads(open(path).read())
    descriptors = []
    for i in xrange(len(descriptors_list )):
        temp = descriptors_list[i] * 1
        descriptors.append(temp)
    descriptors = np.asarray(descriptors)
```

It's working without problem on Python2.7, but, I tried to adapt the code to Python 3 as follows:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pickle #or import _pickle as pickle
    import cv2

    keypoints_list = pickle.loads(open(path).read())
    kp = []
    for point in keypoints_list:
        temp = cv2.KeyPoint(x=point[0][0], y=point[0][1], _size=point[1], _angle=point[2], _response=point[3],
                            _octave=point[4], _class_id=point[5])
        kp.append(temp)
```

And it's return:

> index = pickle.loads(open(path).read())
>   TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I thought, well, I will add the string as bytes. I tried the follow:

```
    keypoints_list = pickle.loads(open(path).read().encode())
    kp = []
    for point in keypoints_list :
        temp = cv2.KeyPoint(x=point[0][0], y=point[0][1], _size=point[1], _angle=point[2], _response=point[3],
                            _octave=point[4], _class_id=point[5])
        kp.append(temp)
```

And descriptors...:

```
        descriptors_list = pickle.loads(open(path).read().encode())
        descriptors = []
        for i in range(len(descriptors_list)):
            temp = descriptors_list[i] * 1
            descriptors.append(temp)
        descriptors = np.asarray(descriptors)
```

With this, **Keypoints load correctly**, but, pickle.loads with descriptors return this:

> index = pickle.loads(open(path).read().encode()) UnicodeDecodeError:
>   'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 2: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

I tried also:

```
    with open(path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        index = pickle.loads(f.read().encode())
    descriptors = []
    for i in range(len(index)):
        temp = index[i] * 1
        descriptors.append(temp)
    descriptors = np.asarray(descriptors)
```

And other derivates... but always return same error.

I see that descriptors are of type cnumpy.core.multiarray, but i don't know how to solve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... I solve this using  [np.fromfile(path)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html#numpy.fromfile)

Code:

```
        descriptors_list = np.fromfile(path)
        descriptors = []
        for i in range(len(descriptors_list)):
            temp = descriptors_list[i] * 1
            descriptors.append(temp)
        descriptors = np.asarray(descriptors)
```