# python 3.6: Error: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when reading a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I am trying read a file with following code.

```
filenames = os.listdir(path)
    data = []
    for file in filenames:
        file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
        print (file_path)
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            try:
                soundId = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
                print (soundId)
                content = f.read()
                pp = pickle.loads(content)
                pp = np.asarray(pp)            
                data[soundId] = pp
            except Exception as e:
                print ("Error occurred" + str(e))
```

when i run the code it give me
Error occurreda bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

The error occurs at the line pp = pickle.loads(content)

There are other questions with similar issue but none of them helped.

I am trying to read a melspectogram data of audio file.
[Sample file i am trying to read](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bfi63vlds4f1-75aKenQ10ERBVb7zGly/view?usp=sharing)

How do i fix this?

Comment: Change `'r'` to `'rb'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:` instead of `with open(file_path, 'r') as f:`

or use `content.encode()` for explicit bytes conversion.

### Update

Your question is related to [how-load-cv2-keypoint-and-descriptors-correctly-on-opencv-3-with-python-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457690/how-load-cv2-keypoint-and-descriptors-correctly-on-opencv-3-with-python-3)

Use below code , it should work:

```
# blues.00000.pp
import pickle, numpy as np
pp_list = np.fromfile('blues.00000.pp')
print('pp_list type :' + str(type(pp_list)))
pp = []
data = dict()
soundID = 'ppFile1'
for i in range(len(pp_list)):
    temp = pp_list[i] * 1
    pp.append(temp)
pp = np.asarray(pp)
print('pp data : ' + str(pp))
data[soundID] = pp
print('ppdata dic :' + str(data))
```

### Output

```
pp_list type :<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
pp data : [4.56259939e+257 4.78104776e+180 9.28824150e+242 ... 1.00603813e+165
 6.01326204e-067 1.55998657e-259]
ppdata dic :{'ppFile1': array([4.56259939e+257, 4.78104776e+180, 9.28824150e+242, ...,
       1.00603813e+165, 6.01326204e-067, 1.55998657e-259])}
```

Comment: I got this error when made the change you suggested.Error occurred'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: i tried both changes you suggested. i got the same error in both cases. I am trying to read a melspectogram of audiodata file

Comment: sys.getdefaultencoding() is 'utf-8'